# Can I ask if a substring is part of a string using C preprocessor directives?

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor

Will present the question first, then the reasoning behind it.

**Question:** Can I ask if a substring is part of a string **at compile time**? i.e. Can I use preprocessor logic to ask whether "Subst" is part of the string "Text1 Subst Text2..."?

**Reasoning:** I work on this large C code base, which has a given tracing framework. This framework allows turning on traces based on trace levels - error, warning, info, debug. This is enabled at compile time, meaning that the strings in the debug traces won't even get compiled if trace level doesn't include the debug level. So far nothing new.

Now, in addition, this framework requires modules to specify their trace group as a string.
e.g. `#define TRACE_GROUP "GRP1"`.
Trace group is displayed in traces and allows filtering traces according to groups - but in run time. This is done using simple C substring functions.

What I'm asking is whether there's a way to do it in compile time. i.e. ask if a trace group is part of a set (like "Grp1 Grp3 Grp7") using preprocessor directives. Reason I need it is the fact that the system is limited in code size. Turning on trace level will fill it with undesirable strings from all modules, while all I want to include is strings from specific modules.

Didn't see any apparent way to accomplish that, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correct: Currently you compile the code with something like "DEBUGLEVEL=info" which enables info-level on all modules. Now you want to do something like "DEBUGLEVEL=info GROUPS='gr1 gr3'" so that debug level info only gets enabled for modules that are in trace group 1 and 3. Is that it?

Comment: That is precisely what I need. Actually I already have it now, but in run time. i.e. if I have GROUPS defined with gr1 and gr3 defined, then debug level info is enabled for these groups, but the debug strings for all other groups are compiled in as well.

Comment: Can you post some code to show how it's handled today.

Comment: "At compile time" and "done by the preprocessor" are two different things. Lots of optimizations are done at compile time, but only after the preprocessor is done. The better question is something focused on the problem you're trying to solve -- "how can I test whether a preprocessor with a list contains a specific flag?" or such.

Comment: @4386427 posting some representing snippets, as the code itself could be better written.

So for instance, the trace debug function looks like this:

`#if TRACE_MAX_LEVEL >= TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG
#define tr_debug(...)           trace_func(TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG,   TRACE_GROUP, __VA_ARGS__) 
#else
#define tr_debug(...)
#endif`


trace_func includes, among the rest, some filtering code like this:

`if (strstr(trace_group, include_group) != 0) 
            return;`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I ask if a substring is part of a string at compile time?

No, you can't.

> This framework allows turning on traces based on trace levels - error, warning, info, debug

> ask if a trace group is part of a set

So use integer flags separately for that.

```
#define GROUP1 0x01
#define GROUP2 0x02
#define ENABLED_GROUPS  (GROUP1 | GROUP2)
#define IS_GROUP_ENABLED(x)  ((ENABLED_GROUPS & x) == x)
```

> this framework requires modules to specify their trace group as a string

So use separate macro for enabling the group and separate for specifying the string to be displayed for the "trace group".

> Reason I need it is the fact that the system is limited in code size.

Enable compiler optimizations - with string literals and `gcc` compiler should be able remove calls to `strstr` or `strchr`. To be sure, just use integer flags and use preprocessor `#if` stememnts.

I recently worked with ZephyrOS, take a look at their [logging](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/reference/logging/index.html#logging-in-a-module). The prefix that is configured separately from loglevel for modules.

---

You "could" unroll `strstr` function and write something that does no external calls and expands to something that is easy to optimize for the compiler:

```
#define STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, i) \
    (a)[i] != (b)[i] ? 0 : !(b)[i + 1] ? 1 :
#define STRSTR_CMP(a, b)  (\
    !(b)[0] ? 1 : \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 0) \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 1) \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 2) \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 3) \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 4) \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 5) \
    STRSTR_CMP_IN(a, b, 6) \
    /* TODO: Add more for longer strings */ \
    0)

#define STRSTR_IN(s, h, i) \
    !(s)[i] ? ((void*)0) : STRSTR_CMP(&(s)[i], (h)) ? &(s)[i] :
#define STRSTR(s, h)  (\
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 0) \
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 1) \
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 2) \
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 3) \
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 4) \
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 5) \
    STRSTR_IN(s, h, 6) \
    /* TODO: Add more for longer strings */ \
    0)
```

Still:

```
// ERROR - you can't use subscript operator in the preprocessor.
#if STRSTR("abc", "b")
```

But it might be easier for your compiler to optimize it out (but ex. `gcc` compiler optimizes out `strstr` calls anyway). (You could also move to C++, they have `constexpr`). Still there [might be a good chance](https://godbolt.org/z/9EvGxb) that `if (STRSTR("Text1 Subst Text2...", "Subst"))` will be optimized to just `if(1)` by your compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess from your first sentence that what I ask is not doable. As for the rest of your suggestions (like integer flags or moving to C++), I'm afraid they won't help in this case. As I said - it's an existing trace framework (I'd probably implement it differently).

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to define each trace group identifier as a macro that expands to a power of 2 integer constant so that they can be formed into a set, for example:

```
#define GRPA (1U << 0)
#define GRPB (1U << 1)
#define GRPC (1U << 2)
```

The module can define the `TRACE_GROUP` macro to expand to one of those group identifiers, for example:

```
#define TRACE_GROUP GRPA
```

The enabled trace groups can be specified in a macro (here, `ENABLED_TRACE_GROUPS`) set at compile time to expand to the identifiers of the enabled trace groups separated by `|`, for example:

```
$ cc -DENABLED_TRACE_GROUPS="GRPA | GRPB" -c foo.c
```

In an include file (here, "trace.h") that implements the tracing macro, the `TRACE_GROUP` macro can be compared to the known constants to define a macro (here, `TRACE_GROUP_STR`) that expands to a string, for example:

**trace.h**

```
#ifndef TRACE_H__INCLUDED__
#define TRACE_H__INCLUDED__

/* Trace groups: */
#define GRPA (1U << 0)
#define GRPB (1U << 1)
#define GRPC (1U << 2)

/* define TRACE_GROUP_STR corresponding to TRACE_GROUP as a string */
#ifdef TRACE_GROUP
#if TRACE_GROUP == GRPA
#define TRACE_GROUP_STR "GRPA"
#elif TRACE_GROUP == GRPB
#define TRACE_GROUP_STR "GRPB"
#elif TRACE_GROUP == GRPC
#define TRACE_GROUP_STR "GRPC"
#else
#define TRACE_GROUP_STR "GRPunk"
#endif
#else
#define TRACE_GROUP_STR "GRPundef"
#endif

/*
 * Define the TRACE(...) macro to either call trace(TRACE_GROUP_STR, ...)
 * or do nothing.
 */
#if defined(TRACE_GROUP) && defined(ENABLED_TRACE_GROUPS) && \
    (TRACE_GROUP & ENABLED_TRACE_GROUPS)
#define TRACE(...) trace(TRACE_GROUP_STR, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define TRACE(...) ((void)0)
#endif

/* The trace() function. */
void trace(const char *grp, const char *fmt, ...);

#endif
```

The `trace()` function declared within "trace.h" can be defined in some utility .c file (here, "trace.c") as required, for example:

**trace.c**

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "trace.h"

void trace(const char *grp, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", grp);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
}
```

Example usage:

**main.c**

```
#define TRACE_GROUP GRPA
#include "trace.h"

int main(void)
{
    TRACE("Hello");
    TRACE("world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Example build:

```
$ cc -DENABLED_TRACE_GROUPS="GRPA | GRPB" main.c trace.c -o tracetest
```

Example run:

```
$ ./tracetest
GRPA: Hello
GRPA: world!
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said in the question (and also in the comment to the previous answer), this is not something I can change. I'm plugged to an existing tracing framework, which imposes the definition of trace groups as strings. There are already dozens of modules from the existing code base that already define the trace groups as strings. Not going to change that. Best I can do is to improve the tracing framework a bit, without breaking the code completely.